# How do I save this to overwrite text on an html page?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
app.post("/web/on_call", function(req, res) {
    var position = req.query.position;
    app.models.call_lists.findOne( { name: req.query.list }).lean().exec(function (err, call_list) {
        var userStatus = req.user.name;
        position.name = userStatus;         
        res.redirect('/web/status');    
    });
});
```

What do I need to write in the file for it to save

Comment: To save _what_ to where?

Comment: What do you mean to save?

Comment: @SLaks I have an html page that lists my friends status as primary, and there is a log in on the html page that recognizes it's me, I want to overtake his primary by clicking a button

Comment: you need text change on click ?

Comment: please show your demo http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You need to write server-side code with a view engine to look up the value from the database and display it in the view.